# Autolayout redraws when animating

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

So I have a **Parent** (ViewController) and a **SubView** (Slider) in which the SubView has a datePicker and a button.

The Subview itself is a class that uses auto layout to put the datePicker and Button in place so when this view is called, the datePicker and button are in place universally with different screen size of iPhones.

**The Problem:** When this subView (Slider) is called from the parent view, it seems that the components inside this view are drawn on runtime from left to right and it looks bad in my opinion.

Below is a bit of the code I have and **I have commented out several parts of the components to begin solving the button issue first ** with no success yet.

```
import UIKit

class Slider: UIView {

var title : UILabel = UILabel()
var testPicker : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
var txtfield : UITextField = UITextField()

var SVSetButton: UIButton = UIButton()


   override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    //self.title.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 30, width: 200, height: 40)
    self.title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.title.text = "Child Object"
    self.title.textAlignment = .center
    self.title.font = UIFont(name: "avenir", size: 26.0)

    self.txtfield.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width:      self.self.bounds.width, height: 35)
    self.txtfield.placeholder = "Text"

    self.testPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.testPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    self.SVSetButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.SVSetButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    self.SVSetButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.alizarinColor()
    //self.SVSetButton.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(DateView.SaveRemindingData), for: .touchUpInside)

    //self.addSubview(testPicker)
    self.addSubview(SVSetButton)
//          self.addSubview(txtfield)


}


override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
    self.title.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.SVSetButton.layoutIfNeeded()
}



override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    //        let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.title, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    //        
    //        
    //        let centerBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.title, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)
    //        
    //        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.title, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 60)
    //        
    //        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.title, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant: -15)


    // MARK: - Date picker test



       //        let pcenterX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.testPicker, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
      //        
      //        
      //        let pcenterBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item:     self.testPicker, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.SVSetButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)
      //        
      //        let pheight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.testPicker,  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 160)
      //        
      //        let pwidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.testPicker, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant: -15)



    let buttonCenterX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.SVSetButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)


    let buttonCenterBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.SVSetButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)

    let buttonHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.SVSetButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)

    let buttonWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.SVSetButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant: -15)



    self.addConstraints([/*pcenterX, pcenterBottom, pheight, pwidth,*/ buttonCenterX, buttonCenterBottom, buttonHeight, buttonWidth])


}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

And here is the snippet that invokes this slider in the parent view using auto layout.

**ViewController (Parent)**

```
    func invokeRemindForm(){

    self.card.textpad.resignFirstResponder()

    self.sliderBackground.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTap)


    slideView = Slider(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2))

    slideView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sliderOpen = true

    if sliderOpen {
        self.remindButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    if let slider = slideView {

       // view.addSubview(slider)
        view.addSubview(sliderBackground)
        self.sliderBackground.addSubview(slider)
        sliderBackground.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)

        // This value may  not be working entirely
        sliderBackground.alpha = 1.0
        sliderBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)


        //  Autolayout
        let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.slideView!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.slideView!, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.slideView!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.slideView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)

        self.slideView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.addConstraints([leading, trailing, bottom, height])

    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I seem to think that auto layout in the slider should hold all the components in place and should not draw themselves when the view is called. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think so. For me your sliderView is placed on the bottom with the total hight/2 and the button is on the bottom centered...

Comment: I know that, but I mean when the button is constrained with auto layout, it somehow re-draws itself while the slide up animating is occurring. In other words, it is not in place when the sliding is happening. For me it redraws itself from left to right where I can see the button draw itself while the slide is happening. this also happens with any other object placed in the slider such as a UIDatePicker and Textfield

Comment: first of all, shrink your sample code to test on myself, I still don't get it .. :(